# Unity3D Cursor.visible and OnEnable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, cursor

I find a strange behavioural when trying to enable cursor.

this Work as Expect

```
void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("enabled");
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
}
```

this won't at all

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Debug.Log("enabled");
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
}
```

both printing to console, But in OnEnabled cursor remain hidden, the script is enabled

My last try is this

```
void Start()
{
    EnableCursor();
}

void EnableCursor()
{
    Debug.Log("enabled");
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Debug.Log(Cursor.visible);
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
}
```

works same

but

```
void OnEnable()
{
    EnableCursor();
}

void EnableCursor()
{
    Debug.Log("enabled");
    Cursor.visible = true;
    Debug.Log(Cursor.visible);
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
}
```

is not working

Comment: The code works fine for me. There must be something else locking the cursor.

Comment: When I use the Start version, the script work, after renaming to OnEnabled, to it won't work. I already check the cursor locking everywhere.

Comment: Try to replicate the test by creating a new empty scene and attach the `OnEnable` script to the camera and run it, it should work. The problem is not in the code, is in something else in the scene.

Comment: But why it works when the same code is in Start function -  I need it to run always when the gameObject is enabled?

Comment: What's happening on both code? What do you expect to happen with each code?

Comment: The first makes cursor visible, and then lock the cursor to center after that is unlocked for the user to move, the second one should do the same, but not. both printing to console.

Comment: https://youtu.be/6kf2WqzFmKY

Comment: That's some weird stuff and I consider it it as a bug.

Comment: @JiříKořenek the most probable cause is that another script disables the cursor after the `OnEnable` method is called in your script but before `Start` is.

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick fix till Unity fix this up.

So code is here

public bool enable = false;

```
void OnEnable()
{
    enable = true;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    if (enable)
    {
        Debug.Log("enabled");
        Cursor.visible = true;
        Debug.Log(Cursor.visible);
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        /*Your Cursor changing code*/
    } 
    enable = false;
}
```

Explanation: I seem to unity keep track of what call the function - and when the function is called from OnEnable all Cursor code not work.